# ¿Cómo se declara un array bidimenesional en bash?

Tags: array, bash

¿Alguien podría postear un ejemplo de cómo se puede declarar un array de arrays en bash?

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con este codigo creas un array de 2 dimensiones (`matrix[$i,$j]`) pero puedes hacerlo de n-dimensiones (`matrix[$i,$j,...,$n]`)

Este codigo crea un array de dos dimensiones con 4 filas y 5 columnas y lo rellena con numeros random

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A matrix
num_rows=4
num_columns=5

for ((i=1;i<=num_rows;i++)) do
    for ((j=1;j<=num_columns;j++)) do
        matrix[$i,$j]=$RANDOM
    done
done
```

Sacado de SO english (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16487258/how-to-declare-2d-array-in-bash)